# Table borders don't display with xhtml2pdf

Tags: html, css, django, xhtml2pdf

I'm using xhtml2pdf with Django to output a page that contains several tables; the html view displays exactly as I want it but the PDF output has no table borders displayed.

The CSS (in the template, not linked) is:

```
     body {
          font-size:11pt;
          line-height:13pt;
          font-family:Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
      }
      table.table-bordered, table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th, table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
          border-top-width: 1pt;
          border-top-style: solid;
          border-top-color: #000000;
          border-bottom-width: 1pt;
          border-bottom-style: solid;
          border-bottom-color: #000000;
          border-left-width: 1pt;
          border-left-style: solid;
          border-left-color: #000000;
          border-right-width: 1pt;
          border-right-style: solid;
          border-right-color: #000000;
          padding-top: 12pt;
          padding-right: 12pt;
          padding-bottom: 12pt;
          padding-left: 12pt;
      }
      .border-top {
          border-top-width: 1pt;
          border-top-style: solid;
          border-top-color: #000000;
      }
      td th table {
          width: 100%;
          vertical-align: center;
          text-align:center;
      }
      table {
          margin-top:auto;
          margin-right:auto;
          margin-bottom:auto;
          margin-left:auto;
          display:block;
      }
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? i'm  having the same problem trying to get a table border around my <tbody> over multiple pages

Comment: No, sorry -- the project went into keep-the-lights-on mode

Answer (score 4):

This answer does not relate with Django but only with the Subject!!

If any one ends up here please take a note:

> Supported CSS properties
>
> xhtml2pdf supports the following standard CSS properties
>
> background-color
> border-bottom-color, border-bottom-style, border-bottom-width
> border-left-color, border-left-style, border-left-width
> border-right-color, border-right-style, border-right-width
> border-top-color, border-top-style, border-top-width
> colordisplay
> font-family, font-size, font-style, font-weight
> height
> line-height, list-style-type
> margin-bottom, margin-left, margin-right, margin-top
> padding-bottom, padding-left, padding-right, padding-top
> page-break-after, page-break-before
> size
> text-align, text-decoration, text-indent
> vertical-align
> white-space
> width
> zoom

link: [reference](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/doc/source/reference.rst)

Took me a while to figure out that it doesn't support border property rather it only supports border-[top/left/right/bottom]-[style/color/width] properties

Comment: I don't follow - the CSS I used has border-[position]-[style] properties, but they didn't render in the PDF.

Comment: I just used it like this! and it did work...   .border-class { border-bottom-color: grey; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; }

Comment: also keep in mind it has only base properties which i figured out after answering so... You have to use frames for float and etc  check page 19 of https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/xhtml2pdf/latest/xhtml2pdf.pdf for more help https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_html.html

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `border` attribute in your table like this

```
<table border="1"></table>
```